# List of numbers lowest value first, and then by input date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, listview, model-view-controller

So I have a list of prices from a database. I would like to sort it so that the first entry in a list is the entry with the lowest number. And then all other entry are order by input date.
How can this be done?

This is my code, which is  a mess, sorry I'm trying stuff :)

````
            var itemPriceDate = itemPrice.OrderBy(d => d.Invoice.DateInvoice).ToList();
            var itemPriceDateLow= itemPriceDate.OrderBy(c => c.qtPrice).ThenBy(d => d.Invoice.DateInvoice);
            ViewBag.ItemPrice = itemPriceDateLow; ```
````

Comment: No matter how you do this, you are going to need an aggregate value (min), which basically means going over the list twice.  Since that is the case, I would recommend that you don’t try for a 1-liner and instead break it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out the lowest value from the List(itemPrice).

```
double lowest_price = itemPrice.Min(c => c.qtPrice);
```

Next, remove the lowest element from the list.

```
var itemToRemove = itemPrice.Single(c => c.qtPrice == lowest_price);
itemPrice.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Next, sort the remaining list based on input Date.

```
var newList = itemPrice.OrderByDescending(d => d.Invoice.DateInvoice).ToList();
```

Finally, add lowest element at first index

```
newList.Insert(0, lowest_price);
```

Comment: So this was 99% good. In my example I needed to do this.

decimal lowest_price = (decimal)itemPrice.Min(c => c.qtPrice);
var itemToRemove = itemPrice.Single(c => c.qtPrice == lowest_price);
itemPrice.Remove(itemToRemove);
var newList = itemPrice.OrderByDescending(d => d.Invoice.DateInvoice).ToList();
newList.Insert(0, itemToRemove);

Comment: So there is one problem with: 
"var itemToRemove = itemPrice.Single(c => c.qtPrice == lowest_price);"

If there is two or more of same qtPrice == lowest_price it throews an error.

Comment: If there are multiple same values, you may try RemoveAll to remove all the matching elements from List. itemPrice.RemoveAll(c => c.qtPrice == lowest_price)

Comment: Thx for your commenst's, but this is not the way to go for me. It works, but onli if the prices are unique.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is great when it works, but it sometimes does unexpected things. Depending on how large your dataset is, you may be better off doing it as a stored procedure that returns the data already ordered.

If the dataset is small or you're cornered into using C# to do it there is the option of using a custom sort function. Without knowing the exact structure of your data, this is more intended as a blanket example that will need tweaking accordingly.

Let's say your list is stored in the itemPrice variable, if you do something along the lines of:

```
itemPrice.Sort((a, b) => {
                  int retVal = a.qtPrice < b.qtPrice;
                  return ret != 0 ? ret : a.Invoice.DateInvoice < b.Invoice.DateInvoice;
              });
```

Will sort by qtPrice and then fall back to the DateInvoice field; you may need to swap the less than to a greater than to get your desired order.

Answer (score 0):

One sort is enough. What I think it should be is:

```
var itemPriceDateLow= itemPriceDate.OrderBy(c => c.qtPrice).ThenBy(d => d.Invoice.DateInvoice);
```

This will obviously give you whole collection. You might want to use .First() if you want to get top most element.

One thing to remember - ThenBy, OrderBy are ascending by default.

Take a look at this example:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemPrice> items = new List<ItemPrice>();
        items.Add(new ItemPrice() { Date = DateTime.Now, QtyPrice = 1});
        items.Add(new ItemPrice() { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), QtyPrice = 1});
        items.Add(new ItemPrice() { Date = DateTime.Now, QtyPrice = 2});

        var sortedItem = items.OrderBy(p => p.QtyPrice).ThenBy(p => p.Date).First();
        Console.WriteLine($"Default Ascending sort {sortedItem.Date}, {sortedItem.QtyPrice}");

        var sortedItemWithReverseDate = items.OrderBy(p => p.QtyPrice).ThenByDescending(p => p.Date).First();
        Console.WriteLine($"Descending sort on date {sortedItemWithReverseDate.Date}, {sortedItemWithReverseDate.QtyPrice}");
    }
}

class ItemPrice {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyPrice { get; set; }
}
```

It will give you:

Default Ascending sort 16/08/2021 12:47:34, 1
Descending sort on date 17/08/2021 12:47:34, 1

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate the collection twice in this case, since you would first need to know the Aggregate Value (Min). Then, you could use a Custom Comparer as the following.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<Item> 
{
    private int _minValue;
    public CustomComparer(int minValue)
    {
        _minValue= minValue;
    }

    public int Compare(Item instanceA, Item instanceB)
    {
        if(instanceA.Price == _minValue) return -1;
        if(instanceB.Price == _minValue) return 1;
        return instanceA.InputDate.CompareTo(instanceB.InputDate);
    }
}
```

Now you can fetch the result as

```
var min = list.Min(x=>x.Price);
var result = list.OrderBy(x=>x,new CustomComparer(min));
```

Example,

```
public class Item
{
    public int Price{get;set;}
    public DateTime InputDate{get;set;}
}
var list = new List<Item>
{
        
        new Item{Price = 2,  InputDate=new DateTime(2021,3,1)},
        new Item{Price = 12, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,7,1)},
        new Item{Price = 12, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,9,1)},
        new Item{Price = 42, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,1,1)},
        new Item{Price = 32, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,6,1)},
        new Item{Price = 22, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,4,1)},
        new Item{Price = 2,  InputDate=new DateTime(2021,3,2)},
        new Item{Price = 12, InputDate=new DateTime(2021,2,1)}
};
    
var min = list.Min(x=>x.Price);
var result = list.OrderBy(x=>x,new CustomComparer(min));
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all your inputs.

For me the right way to go was.

Order my "itemPrice" list by "OrderByDescending(by date)"

Then find out the lowest value from the List(itemPrice).

`double lowest_price = itemPrice.Min(c => c.qtPrice);`

Then declare a new List

`List<qtInvoice> newItemPrice = new List<qtInvoice>();`

First loop that adds all the "lowest_price" to "newItemPrice" list

```
foreach (var item in itemPriceDate)
            {
                if (item.qtPrice == lowest_price)
                {
                    newItemPrice.Add(item);
                }
            }
```

Then in second loop you add all the rest of the prices to "newItemPrice" list

```
foreach (var item in itemPriceDate)
            {
                if (item.qtPrice != lowest_price)
                {
                    newItemPrice.Add(item);
                }
            }
```